# Start External Activity for Result and Return to Requesting Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two applications, call them app 1 and app 2, and am starting an activity in app 2 from app 1 for a result.

The activity in app 2 has an `activity-alias` applied to it so I can add an action (used to start it), and requires a signature-level permission (shared with app 1).

The code used to start the app 2 activity from app 1 is simple:

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent(MY_CUSTOM_ACTION);
startActivity.setPackage(APP2_PACKAGE);
startActivity.putExtra(EXTRA_SOME_PARAM, ...);
startActivityForResult(startActivity, 1234);
```

This results in the activity appearing as expected. I then get some user input, and clean up app 2's activity like so:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, someData);
finish();
```

What I am expecting to happen, is for the calling activity in app 1 to be restored to the foreground and so `onActivityResult` to be called, but what is actually happening, is that app 2's main/launch activity is started instead.

Sometimes I get the `onActivityResult` callback with the right response code and data, but app 1's activity is still stopped.

My understanding of Android led me to believe that app 2's activity would have been part of app 1's task stack (and opening the task switcher bears this out), and so finishing it would just pop back to the caller.

I've tried:

- enabling task reparenting on the app 2 activity
- zeroing out the flags on the `startActivity` Intent
- ensuring that app 2's activity doesn't try to start any other activities
- tracing through the Activity lifecycle to see what's happening, but all trails go cold at `NativeActivityManager`...
- clearing any existing tasks that app 2 has open
- finishing app 2's activity with `finishAffinity` (doesn't work when returning a result)

None of this seems to have an effect. Many of the Intent flags and launch modes aren't allowed when starting for a result, so I'm at a loss for what to try next.

Thanks!

Here's the `<activity>` definitions from the manifest in case it matters:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.App2Activity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:theme="@style/Some.Theme"
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".activity.App2ActivityAlias"
    android:permission="x.y.z.MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION"
    android:targetActivity=".activity.App2Activity"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="x.y.z.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity-alias>
```